# Spring profile default behaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a spring profile "DEV" and thats the only profile I have and I do NOT want to create a "production" profile. So only when profile is "DEV" I would like a certain type of bean for spring security is initiated (which is an in memory guest user and a userdetails bean)

But if no spring profile is provided in my tomcat startup, which is the case in production, I would like my app to continue what it is already doing(using ldap authenticatin provider).

Is there a way to define a "default" bean behaviour without actually needing to provide a profile at start up? Or you can look at my code below and suggest a different solution maybe.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, final AuthenticationProvider provider) throws Exception {

        auth
                .eraseCredentials(false)
                .authenticationProvider(provider)
                .authenticationProvider(jwtConfig.jwtAuthenticationProvider());
}


@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    final LdapUserDetailsService ldapUserDetailsService = new LdapUserDetailsService(ldapUserSearch(), ldapAuthoritiesPopulator());
    return new CompositeUserDetailsService(Arrays.asList(technicalUserDetailsService(), ldapUserDetailsService));
}

@Bean
@Profile("DEV")
public UserDetailsService devUserDetailsService() {
 useAnonymous = true;
        InMemoryUserDetailsManagerBuilder b = new InMemoryUserDetailsManagerBuilder()
                .withUser("user").password("password").authorities(ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN).and();

        return new CompositeUserDetailsService(Arrays.asList(b.build(),
                technicalUserDetailsService()));

}
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() {
    final BindAuthenticator ba = new BindAuthenticator((BaseLdapPathContextSource) contextSource());
    ba.setUserSearch(ldapUserSearch());
    return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(ba, ldapAuthoritiesPopulator());
}
```

Comment: Did you try it already?  If so, did something go wrong?

Comment: By just defining the bean and override it when the profile is active...W which is basically default behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding of what `@Profile` does.  Beans marked with `@Profile` are only loaded when that profile is active, but all other beans (without a `@Profile`) are still always loaded, regardless of the chosen profile.

I see a few ways to solve this:

1) Mark all those beans with a `@Profile("dev")` also with `@Primary` so Spring knows which one to pick when two beans of the same type are loaded (since you donot want to use a production profile).

2) Mark the beans that should **not** be loaded when profile dev is active with `@Profile("!dev")` -- only applicable for Spring 3.2 and higher (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/bcd44f3798ed06c0704d2a3564b8a9735e747e87).

Or...

3) Use a production profile and simply activate it in for example the `web.xml` file (something which you probably don't use locally).

Simply create multiple `@Configuration` classes and mark the entire class with a profile (it also helps to keep related stuff together).  A typical example is for the database.  Create one configuration class for the production database (something with JNDI and Oracle) and one for local development and testing (HSQLDB).

You mark the JNDI Configuration class with `@Profile("production")` and the other with  `@Profile("dev")` -- no need to mark individual beans, just split them logically amongst two different `@Configuration` classes.

This worked really well for us, also when combined with integration testing.

Comment: tnx, your first solution seems to work fine for picking up the correct beans, but somehow i still cant login with my guest user. is there a way to use "auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())" when it is dev profile and  "auth.authenticationProvider(provider)" when NOT dev? which is configured in the first method in my example

Comment: It looks a bit incomplete to answer that... however, I think you should just make two `AuthenticationManager` beans, one with `dev` profile and one without (or with `!dev`).  In those two methods you can then build the bean differently according to the profile.

Comment: thanks. Btw Primary annotation didnt work for me and I used the "!DEV" syntax

Comment: The `!dev` solution is prefered anyway, I only suggested to try `@Primary` because you didn't want to use a production profile.

Answer (score 0):

I would override the bean definition in this way:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, final AuthenticationProvider provider) throws Exception {

        auth
                .eraseCredentials(false)
                .authenticationProvider(provider)
                .authenticationProvider(jwtConfig.jwtAuthenticationProvider());
}


@Bean("myUserDetailService")
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    final LdapUserDetailsService ldapUserDetailsService = new LdapUserDetailsService(ldapUserSearch(), ldapAuthoritiesPopulator());
    return new CompositeUserDetailsService(Arrays.asList(technicalUserDetailsService(), ldapUserDetailsService));
}

@Bean("myUserDetailService")
@Profile("DEV")
public UserDetailsService devUserDetailsService() {
 useAnonymous = true;
        InMemoryUserDetailsManagerBuilder b = new InMemoryUserDetailsManagerBuilder()
                .withUser("guest").password("guest").authorities(ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN).and();

        return new CompositeUserDetailsService(Arrays.asList(b.build(),
                technicalUserDetailsService()));

}
@Bean("myAuthProvider")
public AuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() {
    final BindAuthenticator ba = new BindAuthenticator((BaseLdapPathContextSource) contextSource());
    ba.setUserSearch(ldapUserSearch());
    return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(ba, ldapAuthoritiesPopulator());
}

@Bean("myAuthProvider")
@Profile("DEV")
public AuthenticationProvider devAuthenticationProvider() {

   //find a way to return userdetails here

}
```

In this way when the "DEV" profile is started the beans defined in that profile should override the default beans

Sure when you autowire beans you should use the `@Qualifier` annotation

I hope it's useful

Angelo

Comment: Downvoted, because this does not work deterministically. If two `@Bean` definitions are provided with the same name, Spring only calls one of theses methods. And whichever bean is first call it might work or not. Seems to be dependent on the order within the class.